# AutoMapper fails when mapping SortedSet as ctor argument

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Let's say I have the following AutoMapper (v12.0.1) configuration & classes:

```cs
public record Parent(SortedSet<Child> Children);

public record Child(int Index);

public class ChildComparer : IComparer<Child>
{
    public int Compare(Child x, Child y)
    {
        return x.Index.CompareTo(y.Index);
    }
}

var mapper = new MapperConfiguration(
    cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<int, Child>()
            .ForCtorParam("Index", opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
        
        cfg.CreateMap<IEnumerable<int>, Parent>()           
            .ForCtorParam("Children", opt => opt.MapFrom((src, ctx) =>
                new SortedSet<Child>(
                    ctx.Mapper.Map<List<Child>>(src.ToList()),
                    new ChildComparer())));
    })
    .CreateMapper();
```

Then these all work:

```cs
var ints = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
var res = mapper.Map<Child>(2);

var res2 = mapper.Map<List<Child>>(ints);

var resSet = new SortedSet<Child>(
    mapper.Map<List<Child>>(ints),
    new ChildComparer());
```

However, when I try to map a `Parent`, it fails:

```cs
var result = mapper.Map<Parent>(ints); 
// System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.
```

Full error:

```
Unhandled exception. AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.

Mapping types:
IEnumerable`1 -> Parent
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] -> Program+Parent

Type Map configuration:
IEnumerable`1 -> Parent
System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[[System.Int32, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]] -> Program+Parent

Destination Member:
Void .ctor(System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1[Program+Child]), parameter Children

 ---> System.ArgumentException: At least one object must implement IComparable.
   at System.Collections.Comparer.Compare(Object a, Object b)
   at System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1.AddIfNotPresent(T item)
   at System.Collections.Generic.SortedSet`1.System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<T>.Add(T item)
   at lambda_method3(Closure, Object, Parent, ResolutionContext)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at lambda_method3(Closure, Object, Parent, ResolutionContext)
   at Program.Main()
Command terminated by signal 6
```

Any idea why? [Here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sUIFVC)'s also a .Net Fiddle.

And yes, I'd like to use `.ForCtorParam(...)` and a comparer class for the use-case I have, if possible.

Comment: It's easier to use `ConvertUsing` instead of `ForCtorParam`.

Comment: That does, in fact, work. However, I don't quite see why it shouldn't with `ForCtorParam`.

Comment: Check [the execution plan](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Understanding-your-mapping.html).